# Spell Check/DidYouMean for Japanese language

Tags: nlp, lucene, full-text-search, spell-checking, cjk

looking for ideas for implementing Spellcheck/DidYouMean for the Japanese language (mostly).
The target for spellcheck is search queries, search engine build on solr, but the solution is not bound to it.

So far found two main approached:

- edit distance for dictionary (libraries like SymSpell)
- statistic, based on user rewritten queries

The first approach seems not very feasible for Kanji/Kana.
Also, its results as-is are quite noisy and it's complicated to build a lot of clean N-grams for contextual spellcheck (so 'hollow world' would be fixed as 'hello world').
Any suggestions on how it could be done?

The second approach is complicated because it's difficult to detect rewritten queries and since users rarely do so or do it correctly - it's hard to gather such statistics.

The main articles/videos that I found so far are quite a high level and too simple (for edit distance they don't provide applicable for real-world approaches to reduce noise to a reasonable level - 95% or higher) or focused on English only.

Any pointers for some published papers are welcome :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As someone who only have very rudimentary knowledge of kanjis and japanese input formats from romanization: would this be in regards to kanjis that are graphically similar, or where you got different kanjis after composition from entering them on the keyboard? In the latter case I'd probably start by decomposing it into a sequence of inputs instead, and then consider that for edit distance.

Comment: @MatsLindh It could be either. In fact, one of the ideas is to use both, in order to reduce the noise. Haven't run an experiment yet.

Comment: I'm guessing there have to be a dictionary available somewhere that makes those common misspellings and similarities between kanjis available. You might have to use something like that together with a custom filter that converts those to common tokens for searching.